# Regression tests in R -- how do I initialise my package differently for tests than for production

Tags: r, caching, configuration, r-package, testthat

In detail, I have written a package (not yet published), which uses memoise (https://github.com/hadley/memoise) for caching results that are based on long-lasting-internet-REST-queries. The location of the cache is a configuration option to the package (set by a config file or the environment), and the cached functions have to be initialised while the package loads. The cache shall be deleted manually if needed, since the online data is not updated very frequently.

How do I make my tests use a cache area distinct from the "normal" one

- to prevent accidental overwriting and
- to make the tests reproducible by always starting with an empty cache?

Ideas:

- The problem could have been addressed somewhere in testhat, and I am just too blind to find it.

*Never impossible, of course, I tried to find a solution for some hours before writing here. I saw a similar question regarding databases on stackoverflow -- unanswered.*

- If the package could somehow detect, if it is loaded in a testing-framework, it could use a temporary directory for the cache and ignore the "normal" configuration.

*The only way I found, is commandArgs(). These can differ depending on how the tests are run (devtools, R CMD check, ...), but they always differ from production. Nevertheless, I would have to know all possible/reasonable/usual ways to run tests.*

- If I could call a function during test initialisation before my library is loaded, I could mock an other configuration.

*The testthat.R file in the tests directory is not **always** used, when **is** it used? How is the package-loading accomplished, if the testthat.R file is **not** used, e.g. by devtools?*

EDIT after one day of more thinking over:

1. Detecting, if running from a test: 
   I propose the following code to detect, if code is currently tested (I dislike this option because tests are less useful, if the tested code behaves differently under testing, remember Volkswagen-Diesel motors):

   ```
   testing<-as.logical(any("devtools::test()" == commandArgs()))
   args = commandArgs()[grep("(^|/|\\|:|nextArg)PACKAGE_NAME.Rcheck(nextArg|$)", commandArgs(), perl = TRUE)]
   args2 = unlist(strsplit(args, "nextArg"))
   testing=as.logical(testing || (length(grep("(^|/|\\|:)PACKAGE_NAME.Rcheck$", args2)) > 0))
   ```

((replace PACKAGE_NAME by the name of your package))

2. Work around the problem:
   In my case, I see another option I will now choose, even if this does not answer my question, which I am still interested in. Instead of calling the cache-state-dependent functions in the test, I will have uncached versions of the functions for testing. For production, this version is then encapsulated by memoise. An example with a simple square-function:

   ```
   # not exported
   .f <- function(x) {
     return(x*x);
   }

   # exported
   f <- memoise(.f, cache = c)
   ```

In tests, I can then write:

```
expect_equal(.f(2), 4);
```

But in production:

```
four <- f(2)
```

Sorry for bothering, did not see the obvious, but still, how would you handle such cases? I know of with_mock, but for package initialisation steps, this is not always an option.